# how to gather data for a site like thefreedictionary.com

Tags: content

I was just wondering how the site like "thefreedictionary.com" has so much of content. I mean they have almost an entire dictionary on the web. Many other sites do have this feature. But I would like to know if I wish to start a site like this how can I gather data for this.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary.com have an [api](http://developer.dictionary.com/) you could use to help populate information on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Wikionary is a free and open dictionary published by the Wikimedia foundation. You are free to use it as long as you respect the license requirements. You can start your research here:

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Help:FAQ#Downloading_Wiktionary

Wikimedia volunteer editors can be helpful by providing/improving instructions on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most of them bought the dictionary from companies.

Comment: ok.. dat is an obvious source...
but do you think there can be any other alternative to this..??